# React app with nginx returning blank page

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have a react application that I've deployed using nginx, which however only return a blank page. I've been looking for a solution for the last week and I can say that I tried almost anything... but nothing seems to work.

If I open the console I can see that all of the files are delivered with success, however, I got a "Loading failed for the  with source ..." on firefox and a "net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200" on Chrome. The weird thing is that both files are actually received (200 status) and can be viewed with the development tools. Moreover, if I visit the static resource link I get the full content without problems.
And of course, the issue is only when using the production environment, if I deploy it locally it works perfectly.

I really don't know what to do. I've tried updating the "homepage" directive, playing around with "react-router", changing the various nginx configurations and many other things but nothing.

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running nginx with docker on Raspberry and, for some unknown reason, the timing on the container was completely messed up. I solved the problem by running the container in privileged mode ('privileged: true' on docker-compose)